# Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:9516 (connection refused)

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, automated-tests, capybara

We are running selenium-cucumber tests with capybara.  Each of these tests will pass within the terminal without issue. I know that this error involves a port not being available but I cannot figure out where to fix this and how. When we attempt to run them parallel the first test passes and the remainder fail with this error:

Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:9516 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 9516) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
features/welcome_login.feature:4:in `Given I navigate to "http://www.example.com"'

Here is my env.rb code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-cucumber'
require 'capybara'

# Store command line arguments
$browser_type = ENV['BROWSER'] || 'ff'
$platform = ENV['PLATFORM'] || 'desktop'
$os_version = ENV['OS_VERSION']
$device_name = ENV['DEVICE_NAME']
$udid = ENV['UDID']
$app_path = ENV['APP_PATH']

# check for valid parameters
validate_parameters $platform, $browser_type, $app_path

# If platform is android or ios create driver instance for mobile browser
if $platform == 'android' or $platform == 'iOS'

  if $browser_type == 'native'
    $browser_type = "Browser"
  end

  if $platform == 'android'
    $device_name, $os_version = get_device_info
  end

  desired_caps = {
    caps:       {
      platformName:  $platform,
      browserName: $browser_type,
      versionNumber: $os_version,
      deviceName: $device_name,
      udid: $udid,
      app: ".//#{$app_path}"
      },
    }

  begin
    $driver = Appium::Driver.new(desired_caps).start_driver
  rescue Exception => e
    puts e.message
    Process.exit(0)
  end
else # else create driver instance for desktop browser
  begin
    $driver = Selenium::WebDriver::for(:"#{$browser_type}")
    $driver.manage().window()
  rescue Exception => e
    puts e.message
    Process.exit(0)
  end

end
```

What can I do to get these tests to pass when run parallel (as they do pass when run individually from the terminal?  What code would I write and where would I place this code to get the test to look for an open port?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I am new to automated testing and this has been quite a challenge.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error on MacOs 10.11.6 and the following solved the issue:

Find the chromedriver

```
~/P/m/web-automation (master ⚡↩) which chromedriver
/Users/mesutgunes/.rbenv/shims/chromedriver
```

Remove it

```
rm /Users/mesutgunes/.rbenv/shims/chromedriver
```

Try to re-link it, follow the instruction:

```
~/P/m/web-automation (master ⚡↩) brew link chromedriver
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/chromedriver/2.30...
Error: Could not symlink bin/chromedriver
Target /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite chromedriver

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run chromedriver
```